# ASP.net form resets jquery fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a page with a jquery datepicker. i choose a date and it is all working well. However when the screen refreshes, maybe afdter a button has been pressed. The Date resets to the original value or nothing if no value set.

How do is top this.

jquery code

```
$(function() {
            $('#MyDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
        });
```

inout box code

```
<input type="text" id ="MyDate" />
```

PS I have been using ASP.net/ jquery for about 12 hours, so assume i know nothing. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem specific to jQuery, or even to ASP.NET really. HTML/HTTP is inherently stateless. It doesn't remember anything unless you tell it to. So if your button press submits a form, you must include the date input box in that form, and the value in the box will be passed to the server. The server-side (.NET) code can then process it, and as part of that it can decide to include the value back into the next refresh of the page. There are hundreds of tutorials on how to handle forms and postbacks in ASP.NET, it's probably a good idea to work through some

Comment: Hi, i was using webforms, but am only 10% down the road i guess, could start again using MVC. Happy to be guided down the 'neatest' route.

Comment: MVC has probably got better prospects for the future, and in many ways it's a slightly cleaner method and closer to the way the raw web works, but on the other hand if you've come from a WinForms background, webforms might be easier to get your head around

Answer (score 0):

@Lynxbci Exciting times ahead, there is plenty of tutorials to follow!

I assume you are playing around with .NET MVC correct? if thats the case you should consider using AJAX instead of a form submit. I could go on and on about the benefits but you will have to search and get a meaningful understanding.

A simple resource would be: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/javascript
But I would really recommend you to go through most of the topics in that website as they are really relevant for beginners.

From w3schools, what is AJAX? "AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page."

Alternatively you can do it the very dirty way, by assigning that input to a Model variable alongside Razor, so when you do a post those values are kept in your Model. 
Here is an example of how razor works: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

I could give you code examples but I really believe you need to start with the basics. Provided that you don't state I don't even now if you have web development background because that would help establish some parallelisms.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, i do not have a web development background. I do have years of VB programming, and database design. I am converting a very simple Access Db to ASP.net at someones request. I understand code and in a day have created a SQL server, fed it to my form and added an input form using jquery datepicker, so i learn quite quickly. This one just threw me, as i wasn't aware HTTP/HTML cleared these fields on refresh. I guess i need to store them, and recall in some way. I am not familiar with AJAX, but will look it up. Thanks

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain on my answer above. You can take the quick path were you store all the values and send them back and forth (not great, but hey if it works) or you can take a more correct approach and apply AJAX in a very neat and clean way. You never said if you are using MVC or WebForms